# How to remove headers from all outgoing requests in AWS services (e.g. Lambda)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-lambda, amazon-nat-gateway

Just wondering, is there a way to remove a header from all outgoing network requests in AWS?

I have a VPC with public and private subnets and a NAT gateway in the public subnet. A Lambda in this VPC is making network calls to both internal and external services, with an `X-Amzn-Trace-Id` header, and I was wondering if there's a way to remove this only for outgoing calls, so that they don't go to external services. Maybe somewhere around the NAT gateway?

Comment: You can try turning off AWS X-Ray which is adding that header https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-concepts.html  . There's no way to do this with a NAT Gateway. You might be able to rig up a proxy that does this change and have Lambda use it, but that seems excessive.